# Filtering file using it's type in iOS and put it in an array for specific directory

Tags: objective-c, ios, path

I need to look for files with a specific type and put them in an array. I've found code like this:

```
NSArray* pdfs = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                  pathsForResourcesOfType:@"pdf" inDirectory:nil];
```

But this code accesses my application bundle, not the Documents directory.

I also found this code for getting the Documents directory:

```
NSString* doc = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);;
```

However, I just don't get how to get the path for a pdf file inside the Documents folder. I already tried to change the values of the parameters for `inDirectory:` in pdfs to be `@"~/Documents"` and still it can't change the directory path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abcd.pdf"];
BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentsDirectory];
if (success == YES){
  //Do your stuff here if file found at documents directory
}
else{
  //file not found
}
```

To get the array of files at document directory :

```
NSError **error1;
NSArray *paths2 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory2 = [paths2 objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *array = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory2 error:error1];
```

Comment: is it possible for paths have length more than one? especially when its value is the return value of NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);? because I need to get an array of files not only one files. thx for the response

Comment: thx a lot, I think I've figured out the answer, your code just enlighten me.